# API Connect 2018 Developer portal installation failure

Tags: haproxy, ibm

Good day.

I was installed API Connect 2018 management and portal hosts (version 2018.2.10) using Install Assist utility (apicup). Management server started ok, i see APIConnect is UP after 'apic status' command. But i have problem with deploying developer portal: HAProxy don't started... In /var/log/syslog i see next message:

```
Aug  7 13:27:21 portal systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
```

Application-backend section of HAProxy config file (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg) is:

```
backend application-backend
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    server  192.168.1.12:6443 check
```

I think that 1 parameter is missing in the server definition line (there is only 2 spaces). I think it should look like this:

```
server my_portal_host 192.168.1.12:6443 check
```

The apiconnect-up.yaml file:

```
kind: apiconnect-up
subsystems:
  mgmt:
    endpoints:
    - hostname: apic.test.lo
      name: platform-api
    - hostname: apic.test.lo
      name: consumer-api
    - hostname: apic.test.lo
      name: cloud-admin-ui
    - hostname: apic.test.lo
      name: api-manager-ui
    hosts:
    - hostname: apic.test.lo
      interfaces:
      - device: eth0
        dhcp: false
        gw: 192.168.1.1
        ip: 192.168.1.10
        mask: 255.255.255.0
      password: password
    kvs:
      additional-cloud-init-file: ""
      az-name: us-west
      cassandra-backup-auth-pass: ""
      cassandra-backup-auth-user: ""
      cassandra-backup-host: ""
      cassandra-backup-path: /backups
      cassandra-backup-port: "22"
      cassandra-backup-protocol: sftp
      cassandra-backup-schedule: 0 0 * * *
      cassandra-max-memory-gb: "4"
      cross-az-peers: ""
      data-device: sdb
      default-password: ""
      dns-servers: 192.168.1.1
      k8s-pod-network: 172.16.0.0/16
      k8s-service-network: 172.17.0.0/16
      portal-base-uri: http://portal.test.lo
      public-iface: eth0
      search-domain: test.lo
      search-max-memory-gb: "4"
      ssh-keyfile: ./id_rsa.pub
      traffic-iface: eth0
    target: appliance
    type: management
  port:
    endpoints:
    - hostname: portal.test.lo
      name: portal-admin
    - hostname: devportal.test.lo
      name: portal-www
    hosts:
    - hostname: portal.test.lo
      interfaces:
      - device: eth0
        dhcp: false
        gw: 192.168.1.1
        ip: 192.168.1.12
        mask: 255.255.255.0
      password: password
    kvs:
      additional-cloud-init-file: ""
      az-name: us-west
      data-device: sdb
      default-password: ""
      dns-servers: 192.168.1.1
      k8s-pod-network: 172.16.0.0/16
      k8s-service-network: 172.17.0.0/16
      public-iface: eth0
      search-domain: test.lo
      ssh-keyfile: ./id_rsa.pub
      traffic-iface: eth0
    target: appliance
    type: portal
version: 1.4.0+build.2018.1-1437.time.2018-06-08T04-41-28Z.commit.36f125d
```

What can be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by adding all hostnames (including FQDN) to /etc/hosts on both machines (mgmt and portal):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.2.10 apic
192.168.2.10 apic.test.lo
192.168.1.12 portal
192.168.1.12 portal.test.lo
192.168.1.12 devportal
192.168.1.12 devportal.test.lo
```